Indexing in Julia
I want to set
(1,1),(2,1),(3,3) element of matrix A to be 1.
In python I can do something like.
A=zeros(Int,4,4)
A[[1,2,3],[1,1,3]]=1

This does not work. What is the equivalent in Julia?

this is clearly not what I am asking.
I want specific element to be 1, not all.

The following works (although a for loop likely will be more efficient).
A[CartesianIndex.([(1,1), (2,1), (3,3)])] .= 1

Thank you! This is the notation that I needed/intended. For loop was my last hope, but unlike python probably I should use more for loops in Julia perhaps

Yeah, IMO the for loop is IMO a cleaner solution. Loops are good.

If you have the indices as two vectors (as in question) then you can do A[CartesianIndex.([1,2,3], [1,1,3])] .= 1 instead. Or else setindex!.(Ref(A), 1, [1,2,3], [1,1,3]); A. Both allocate, neither is as quick as a for loop.

Or A[CartesianIndex.(zip([1,2,3], [1,1,3]))] .= 1; A
The following agrees with Oscar Smiths's note about likely performance efficiency.
# Julia 1.10.5
using BenchmarkTools

A = zeros(Int64, 100, 100)
xs = [rand(1:100) for x in 1:100]
ys = [rand(1:100) for y in 1:100]
zs = zip(xs, ys)

@btime ($A)[CartesianIndex.(zip($xs,$ys))] .= 1; nothing
# ... ns (2 allocations: 3.58 KiB)

@btime ($A)[CartesianIndex.($zs)] .= 1; nothing
# ... ns (2 allocations: 3.58 KiB)

@btime for (x, y) in zip($xs, $ys); ($A)[x,y] = 1; end
# ... ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

@btime for (x, y) in $zs; ($A)[x,y] = 1; end
# ... ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)


Why insert zip into these broadcasts? @btime ($A)[CartesianIndex.($xs,$ys)] .= 1; has half the allocations. As does @btime setindex!.(Ref($A), 1, $xs, $ys); although it's slower... and neither is as fast as the for loop.

As far as I can tell, Julia does not support the same simultaneous multiple advanced indexing style for assignment. So, you might need to use a for loop to achieve your desired output:
julia> A = zeros(Int, 4, 4)
4×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0

julia> idx = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3)]
3-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 1)
 (2, 1)
 (3, 3)

julia> for (i, j) in idx
           A[i, j] = 1
       end

julia> A
4×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  0  0  0
 1  0  0  0
 0  0  1  0
 0  0  0  0


Thank you for answering, this is not quite the thing I wanted. I modified one of the indices in the question to (3,3).

Got it, afaict no way to do that in Julia. But maybe someone else will answer.

Thank you, yes, I guess that's the only way to do this... I will accept yours as an answer.
